# Mysqli Prepared Statment Fails each time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Mysqli prepare statement fails in each attempt. I tried many things but they were not working. The code I have is :

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
class Database {
function insertImage($title,$desc,$thumbnail_path,$image_path, $uploaded_by){
    $link = mysqli_connect('DB_SERVER', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_NAME');

    /* check connection */
    if (!$link) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO photos (title, description, thumbnail,image,uploaded_by) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$query);
        if(!$stmt){
            die("NO statement");
        }
        else
        {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sssss',$title,$desc,$thumbnail_path,$image_path,$uploaded_by);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        }
        mysqli_close($link);

    }

}
```

and function runs like this:

```
$db = new Database();
            $db->insertImage($post_title,$post_description,$thumb_path,$full_path,$post_description);
```

Please guide me where I am going wrong. 

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: "NO statement"
that `die("NO statement");` executes.

Comment: Are you sure that the parameter types in your `mysqli_bind_param` are all correct? Check your database for the `uploaded_by` field. It smells like `integer`, and you're passing `string`. May we see the structure of the `photos` table with data types?

Comment: can you try this:
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
//to check if link is set

Comment: There's already a check for connection.

Comment: @avisheks they already have `if (!$link) `

Comment: 1       image_id  int(11) 
 2 title varchar(100) 
 3 description varchar(500)
 4 thumbnail varchar(100) 
 5 image         varchar(100) 
 6 uploaded_by varchar(50)

Comment: The data correctly print on screen when form is submitted.

Comment: @Abrar: If the `die` statement executes, try removing that check. The examples in the documentation don't do that check at all: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php. Perhaps it's a bug.

Comment: Yes,I see that I just want make sure no_error_code set

Comment: When removed die();
**Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\Gallery\connection.php on line 17**

Comment: @Abrar: What's your version of PHP?

Comment: @Luka the code above is copy pasted from this link

Comment: That means your check was valid and your statement indeed fails to prepare

Comment: Apache Version :
2.4.4  
PHP : 5.4.16

Comment: @Abrar: I can't see any other reason why the `prepare` statement would fail apart from something being wrong with your PHP `mysqli` database extension itself. Try reinstalling the `php5-mysql` package if you're on Linux and have access to it.

Comment: @Luka few days ago i was using PHP:PDO which was working very well. but the client request is to use mysqli. 
Am i supposed to reinstall wamp?

Comment: There's no need to reinstall the extension before ruling out all possible code related scenarios. You don't reinstall things if you cant figure out the error right away.

Comment: @Abrar: Try XAMPP or UWAMPP if it's for testing purposes only. There might be something wrong with the dynamic link library for MySQL, I don't know what else to advise. Of course, you can try debugging this, but I'll leave it to you to judge how much time it's worth.

Comment: you need to gain an understanding of the language and how you should use it before attempting anything like this. this is an improperly constructed class and even worse you are storing images in mysql, which will result in poor performance later.

Comment: @r3wt they aren't storing any images in the database. Take hints from here `$thumbnail_path,$image_path`

Answer (score 0):

you are not using class correctly. i suggest you find a tutorial on object oriented programming so you will understand. here is your class rewritten in a basic OO format.

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';
class Database {
    private $conn;//the class property holding your mysqli database object
    function __construct(){
        $this->conn = mysqli_connect('DB_SERVER', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASSWORD', 'DB_NAME');//construct your $mysqli object.
    }
    public function insertImage($title,$desc,$thumbnail_path,$image_path, $uploaded_by){
        try{
            $query = $this->conn->query("START TRANSACTION;");//start the transaction
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO photos (title, description, thumbnail,image,uploaded_by) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");//OO prepared statement
            $stmt->bind_param('sssss',$title,$desc,$thumbnail_path,$image_path,$uploaded_by);//bind params 
            if(!$stmt->execute()){ //if statement doesn't execute
                throw new Exception('problem with query');//throw execption, the statement failed to execute.
            }else{
                $stmt->close();//close the statement
                $query = $this->conn->query("COMMIT;");//commit the transaction
            }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $query = $this->conn->query("ROLLBACK;");//roll the database back removing any partially commited data.
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use transactions for this. Transactions are used when ACID properties are really important like in bank systems. Otherwise it seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: @Luka if the database has columns with default values it will allow for partial data insertion. you obviously read that somewhere and took it ad hominem, but trust me, ACID is critical to application data for multiple purposes, not just bank systems.

Comment: I meant bank systems just as an example, not the exclusive application of transactions. Having default values allowed in the database doesn't make much difference here. If you have allowed default values, transactions aren't going to prevent the insertion of that kind of records.